# C# method allocating unnecessary stack space?

Tags: c#, assembly, stack-overflow

I'm trying to understand some behavior I'm seeing in some C# code, without regard for whether this is how an application *should* be written. Basically, consider the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackTest
{
    class MyClass
    {
        private int x;

        public MyClass(int x)
        {
            this.x = x;
        }
    }

    class DictClass
    {
        private Dictionary<Guid, MyClass> m_dict;
        private Dictionary<int, MyClass> m_intDict;

        public DictClass()
        {
            m_dict = new Dictionary<Guid, MyClass>();
            m_intDict = new Dictionary<int, MyClass>();
            Init(m_dict, m_intDict);
        }

        public void Init(
            Dictionary<Guid, MyClass> dict,
            Dictionary<int, MyClass> intDict)
        {
            int index = 0;
            MyClass obj;

            // BEGIN REPEATED_FRAGMENT
            ++index;
            obj = new MyClass(index);
            dict.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), obj);
            intDict.Add(index, obj);
            // END REPEATED_FRAGMENT

            // Repeat REPEATED_FRAGMENT about 1400 times
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return m_dict.Values.First().ToString();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dc = new DictClass();
            Console.WriteLine(dc);
        }
    }
}
```

In the method Init, it appears that far more space is being allocated on the stack than should be necessary. The following appears in the disassembly window for the method, before any of the actual C# statements:

```
03720568  push        ebp  
03720569  mov         ebp,esp  
0372056B  push        edi  
0372056C  push        esi  
0372056D  push        ebx  
0372056E  test        dword ptr [esp-1000h],eax  
03720575  test        dword ptr [esp-2000h],eax  
0372057C  sub         esp,2C7Ch  
03720582  mov         esi,ecx  
...and so on...
```

If I am reading this correctly, it is allocating about 11 KB of stack space for a method that has 2 parameters and 2 local variables, plus a handful of temporaries. My questions are:

1. Am I reading that correctly?
2. If yes to 1, then why is it allocating all that space?

Again, not really concerned right now with whether you should ever actually write code this way. Just curious what's going on.

Comment: The two test instructions one after another seems odd, but yes, 11,396 of stack is being reserved. I would guess this is not optimized code and in order to give you some of the bells and whistles that are indicative of IDE's this space is needed to build information about the class.

Comment: @Shift_Left: Those are [stack probes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48354730/224132), to make sure you don't touch more than 1 page below the currently allocated stack.  It does it before modifying ESP because a signal/exception handler could use memory below ESP asynchronously.

Comment: Which method is that disassembly from?  Presumably it's somewhere that the compiler has allocated space for a large object on the stack, so (after inlining) it's probably one that has a dictionary object as a local variable that never escapes the function, so the compiler can prove that it can use stack space instead of normal dynamically allocated / garbage-collected space.  (I assume C# does this; That description is actually what I've read for the Go compiler's escape analysis, but it's likely they're designed the same.)

Comment: @PeterCordes It is the disassembly for Init.

Comment: @Shift_Left It still occurs even in an optimized release build. But it subtracts 24E4h from esp instead of 2C7Ch.

Comment: @PeterCordes To clarify, the Dictionary objects are member variables of the class. The object in Main doesn't go anywhere else, but I'm not sure that matters in this scenario. This is a boiled down version of it and not the code that originally made me ask the question.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed the "Repeat REPEATED_FRAGMENT about 1400 times" comment.  If it only happened without optmization, I'd have guessed it was just space for temporaries, and each temporary was getting its own instead of reusing the same slot or keeping it in a register.  But if it happens with optimization too, then maybe it's space for the `new MyClass(index)`.  Check the rest of the asm to see what it's doing with the space: it might be a missed-optimization (failure to reuse space), like maybe space for `Guid.NewGuid()` if it gets passed by reference or something.

Comment: Beyond that, I'm out of ideas; I don't even know or use C#, just x86 asm and how C / C++ compilers typically generate code.

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:stack-overflow]? Are you actually getting a `StackOverflowException` here? 11K is a lot, but default stack on Windows is 1MB, so I wouldn't expect this to actually cause an exception.

Comment: @PeterDuniho With enough repetition, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you examining the disassembly? Using Visual Studio? Or a lower-level debugger like Windbg?

I ask, because looking at the whole disassembled method, it seems clear that the stack space is being used for temporary storage on each call to `new MyClass(index)` and `dict.Add(...)`. For example, here's what I see for the first segment (note bold-face arguments):

```
    39:             ++index;
07980082  inc         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]  
    40:             obj = new MyClass(index);
07980085  mov         ecx,2EA4E30h  
0798008A  call        02E930F4  
0798008F  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax  
07980092  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-10h]
07980095  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]  
07980098  call        dword ptr ds:[2EA4E2Ch]  
0798009E  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-10h]  
079800A1  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4F38h],eax  
    41:             dict.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), obj);
079800A7  lea         ecx,[ebp-20h]  
079800AA  call        72D527F0  
079800AF  lea         eax,[ebp-20h]  
079800B2  sub         esp,10h  
079800B5  movq        xmm0,mmword ptr [eax]  
079800B9  movq        mmword ptr [esp],xmm0  
079800BE  movq        xmm0,mmword ptr [eax+8]  
079800C3  movq        mmword ptr [esp+8],xmm0  
079800C9  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-4F34h]  
079800CF  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-4F38h]  
079800D5  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx  
079800D7  call        72D2DD70  
    42:             intDict.Add(index, obj);
079800DC  push        dword ptr [ebp-4F38h]  
079800E2  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
079800E5  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]  
079800E8  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx  
079800EA  call        72CFF2F0
```

Here's what I see for the second segment:

```
    45:             ++index;
079800EF  inc         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]  
    46:             obj = new MyClass(index);
079800F2  mov         ecx,2EA4E30h  
079800F7  call        02E930F4  
079800FC  mov         dword ptr [ebp-24h],eax  
079800FF  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-24h]  
07980102  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]  
07980105  call        dword ptr ds:[2EA4E2Ch]  
0798010B  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-24h]  
0798010E  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4F38h],eax  
    47:             dict.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), obj);
07980114  lea         ecx,[ebp-34h]  
07980117  call        72D527F0  
0798011C  lea         eax,[ebp-34h]  
0798011F  sub         esp,10h  
07980122  movq        xmm0,mmword ptr [eax]  
07980126  movq        mmword ptr [esp],xmm0  
0798012B  movq        xmm0,mmword ptr [eax+8]  
07980130  movq        mmword ptr [esp+8],xmm0  
07980136  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-4F34h]  
0798013C  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-4F38h]  
07980142  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx  
07980144  call        72D2DD70  
    48:             intDict.Add(index, obj);
07980149  push        dword ptr [ebp-4F38h]  
0798014F  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
07980152  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]  
07980155  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx  
07980157  call        72CFF2F0
```

In other words, stack slots `[ebp-10h]` and `[ebp-20h]` are being used in the first segment, while slots `[ebp-24h]` and `[ebp-34h]` are used in the second segment.

It's been a long time since I've had to worry about what the native compiler is turning the code into. Last time I had to debug a stack-usage issue was literally almost two decades ago. But, it seems clear that the compiler has decided that for some reason, it needs new temporary variables for each of these calls, hence the large allocation.

It's *possible* that in a completely optimized build, i.e. not running under Visual Studio's debugger (which when attached to a process can itself suppress optimizations even for a Release build), the compiler is able to optimize those stack slots, combining them into single variables reused for each call. Hence my question about how you're observing the code.

If you're seeing that output from the JIT compiler even when the code is compiled without the Visual Studio debugger attached, then I don't have a good explanation for why the compiler is not sharing the stack slot for each call. Though, a method that big might cause the optimizer to just give up, which would be explanation enough. :)

Of course, as you already allude to, this is really a completely non-issue. It's not how a sane person would write that code, so the consequences of the insanity are purely academic.

Comment: It's not entirely academic...I did encounter some real code that made me ask the question. That was more of a "yes, I already know it's bad, but I can't explain why it does what it does" thing.

Comment: Examination was done with the Visual Studio debugger, but I don't believe this is being optimized away when not attached. As mentioned in the question comments, with enough repetition it does trigger a stack overflow. This was a much simplified version of the code I actually encountered, but the principle was the same.

Comment: _"I did encounter some real code that made me ask the question"_ -- I guess it depends on one's definition of "academic". I would expect, upon discovering code written that way, the first order of business would be to fix the code. Why it happens is much less interesting than simply knowing that it does, because only the latter bit of information is required in order to improve the program. To me, that makes the "why" academic. But naturally, YMMV.

Comment: Fair enough :) I suppose I'd like to know so I could explain it in detail, but as you say it's not necessary to fix the bigger issue.